# Testing a div based on state using if condition in jest/enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I'm using Jest/Enzyme for testing my react component, but could not cover the lines inside the if statement. Is there a way to test the state and show the `div`? By default the `pageload` will be `false`, and after data fetch it will be changed to `true`.

```
render(){
    if (this.state.pageload) {
      return (<div className="emptyMessage"><span>Empty text</span></div>);
    }
}
```

test code :

```
it('Checks page loading', () => {
  const myContainer = mount(<MuiThemeProvider>
    <IntlProvider locale="en">
    <MyContainer.WrappedComponent  {...props } text={text} tools={tools} />
    </IntlProvider></MuiThemeProvider>);
    myContainer.setState({ pageload: true });
    myContainer.update();
    expect(myContainer.state().pageload).to.equal(true);
    expect(myContainer.find('div').length).toBe(1);
    expect(toJson(myContainer)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: Please post the test code you have so far.

Comment: Updated the codes..

Comment: Which `expect` fails?

Comment: first two expect fails.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the variable as `myContainer`. But you are using `MyContainer` everywhere else. Please correct this.

Comment: Thanks,I've edited.Forgot to update it.But the problem still exists.